# Flutter build appbundle R8: Type com.bundle.id.MainActivity is defined multiple times:

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle

When I run

```
flutter build appbundle
```

it returns with the following error

> ./build/app/intermediates/javac/release/classes/com/bundle/id/MainActivity.class:
>
> R8: Type com.bundle.id.MainActivity is defined multiple
> times:
>
> ./build/app/intermediates/javac/release/classes/com/bundle/id/MainActivity.class,
>
> ./build/app/tmp/kotlin-classes/release/com/bundle/id/MainActivity.class
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong:                                                       Execution failed for task ':app:minifyReleaseWithR8'.
>
> com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete

Where com.bundle.id is my app bundle

It says there are duplicate files called MainActivity. How should I fix this?

Comment: The same here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66164771/type-project-com-project-mainactivity-is-defined-multiple-times