# Type project.com.project.MainActivity is defined multiple times

Tags: java, android, flutter, android-studio, kotlin

Android Application ID conflicts in Kotlin and Java MainActivity classes

Error:

```
Type project.com.project.MainActivity is defined multiple times 
./project/build/app/intermediates/javac/debug/classes/project/com/project/MainActivity.class,
./project/build/app/tmp/kotlin-classes/debug/project/com/project/MainActivity.class
```

Both Kotlin and Java MainActivity classes are generated with the `flutter run` command and both  include  `package project.com.project`

MainActivity.class

```
package project.com.project

public class MainActivity {
   public MainActivity() {
   }
}
```

MainActivity.kt

```
package project.com.project

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {

}
```

Environment :

```
Android Studio  4.1.2
Gradle Plugin       4.1.2 
Gradle Version  6.5 
Flutter Version     1.22
```

Tried in Android Studio :

```
Build -> Clean Project, 
Build -> Rebuild Project, 
File -> Invalidate Cache Restart
```

Tried in Command Line :

```
flutter clean 
flutter run
rm -Rf ~/.gradle/caches
```

The error is still there.

Comment: The issue is pointing to https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes , now let's compare the gradle and Android Studio Dependencies.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The conflict is caused by autogenerated Kotlin references in gradle.

Removing all Kotlin entries from gradle config files is sufficient to get the `flutter run` command back to order

Answer (score 6):

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android' remove this line from app/build.gradle

Answer (score 2):

Removing `Kotlin` entries from `build.gradle` did work for me, but I seemed like a work-around, but not the actual solution. Also `flutter clean` didn't do the job for me.

### **Cause of the problem**

The project I was working on was created with `java` support, rather than `Kotlin`, and for a plugin to work I need the Kotlin folder. Nevertheless, I created the kotlin directly using this command,

```
flutter create -a kotlin .
```

As a result, my product had two class files for `MainActivity` (Inside both Kotlin & Java directories) and I figured it out by digging deep into the build folder, inside `intermediates` and `tmp` sub directories. **This was the actual error, that poped up in the logs.**

### **The Solution**

Then by taking some hints from another of my projects, that had `Kotlin` support, I deleted `com.example.my_project` folder from `android/app/src/main/java` and the error was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for me was that **I had both Java and Kotlin support in my app**. And both the **MainActivity.java** and **MainActivity.kt** had a MainActivity class. Now, there were **two possible solutions** for this:

**1:** Delete one of the folders: Either java or kotlin. whichever is not being used.

**2:** Comment out the MainActivity class in one of them.

I used the 2nd option and this is how I did it:

**Before:**

[image: Before]

**After:**

[image: After]

**P.S. The reason why I choose the 2nd option is that initially, the app had Kotlin support which I removed and added the Java support to add a native module. But then I commented that java based native module because I did not need it anymore. So, I added the Kotlin support again but I also wanted to keep the commented Java code, so I did not delete the Java folder.**