# Flutter MainActivity is defined multiple times error after upgrade

Tags: flutter, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

**What i have done:**
Upgrading to flutter 2.10.2
flutter pub upgrade
flutter clean
flutter pub get

Now i have the following error for 3 days now without finding similar issue here.

```
Execution failed for task ':app:dexBuilderDebug'.
> There was a failure while executing work items
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.dexing.DexWorkAction
      > Failed to process: /Users/****/Code/******/build/app/intermediates/javac/debug/classes, /Users/****/Code/******/build/app/tmp/kotlin-classes/debug
```

Somewhere in the error i also see

```
D8: Type com.simriv.projetge.MainActivity is defined multiple times: /Users/jasonsimard/Code/projetge/build/app/intermediates/javac/debug/classes/com/simriv/projetge/MainActivity.class, /Users/jasonsimard/Code/projetge/build/app/tmp/kotlin-classes/debug/com/simriv/projetge/MainActivity.class
```

Also

```
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.b: Error: /Users/*****/Code/*****/build/app/intermediates/javac/debug/classes/com/****/*****/MainActivity.class, Type com.****.****.MainActivity is defined multiple times: /Users/****/Code/****/build/app/intermediates/javac/debug/classes/com/****/****/MainActivity.class, /Users/****/Code/*****/build/app/tmp/kotlin-classes/debug/com/****/******/MainActivity.class
        at Version.fakeStackEntry(Version_2.0.88.java:0)
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.O0.a(:21)
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.N0.b(:7)
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.N0.a(:27)
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.N0.a(:10)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.merge(ConcurrentHashMap.java:2048)
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.N0.a(:6)
        at com.android.tools.r8.graph.D0$c.f(:3)
        at com.android.tools.r8.dex.a.a(:83)
        at com.android.tools.r8.dex.a.a(:10)
        at com.android.tools.r8.D8.d(:6)
        at com.android.tools.r8.D8.b(:1)
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.W.a(:30)
```

I still don't find where the mainactivity is defined multiple time

Comment: Seems similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66164771/type-project-com-project-mainactivity-is-defined-multiple-times ?