# Application fails to build. A very long flutter error is displayed

Tags: flutter, dart, debugging

I cloned a GitHub repository and obtained all the packages specified in the .yaml file. Upon attempting to run the application using the 'Run Without Debugging' option, I encountered an a very long error that I'm having difficulty understanding. Please can someone help me find root cause of this problem.

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
ERROR:D:\test\eighternityapp\build\app\tmp\kotlin- 
classes\debug\com\example\eighternityApp\MainActivity.class: D8: Type 
com.example.eighternityApp.MainActivity is defined multiple times: 
D:\test\eighternityapp\build\app\tmp\kotlin- 
classes\debug\com\example\eighternityApp\MainActivity.class, D:\test\eighternityapp\build\app\intermediates\javac\debug\classes\com\example\eighternityApp\MainActivity.class
org.gradle.workers.WorkerExecutionException: There was a failure while executing work items
at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor.workerExecutionException(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:267)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor.await(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:249)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexArchiveBuilderTaskDelegate.doProcess(DexArchiveBuilderTaskDelegate.kt:227)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexArchiveBuilderTask.doTaskAction(DexArchiveBuilderTask.kt:254)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.NewIncrementalTask$taskAction$$inlined$recordTaskAction$1.invoke(BaseTask.kt:69)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Blocks.recordSpan(Blocks.java:51)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.NewIncrementalTask.taskAction(NewIncrementalTask.kt:47)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:104)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalInputsTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalInputsTaskAction.java:32)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:51)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AbstractIncrementalTaskAction.execute(AbstractIncrementalTaskAction.java:25)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:29)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$3.run(TaskExecution.java:242)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeAction(TaskExecution.java:227)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeActions(TaskExecution.java:210)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeWithPreviousOutputFiles(TaskExecution.java:193)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.execute(TaskExecution.java:171)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.executeInternal(ExecuteStep.java:89)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.access$000(ExecuteStep.java:40)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:53)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:50)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:50)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:40)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:68)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:38)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:48)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:36)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:41)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:74)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:55)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:51)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:29)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:61)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:42)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:60)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:27)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.executeWithoutCache(BuildCacheStep.java:180)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.lambda$execute$1(BuildCacheStep.java:75)
at org.gradle.internal.Either$Right.fold(Either.java:175)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.caching.CachingState.fold(CachingState.java:59)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:73)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:48)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:36)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:25)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:36)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:22)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:110)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$2(SkipUpToDateStep.java:56)
at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:369)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:56)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:38)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:73)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:44)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:37)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:27)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:89)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:50)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:114)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:57)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:76)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:50)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.executeWithNoEmptySources(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:249)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:86)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:54)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.execute(RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.java:32)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.execute(RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.java:21)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:38)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:43)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:31)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.lambda$execute$0(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:40)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$4.withWorkspace(TaskExecution.java:287)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:40)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:30)
Caused by: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.dexing.DexWorkAction
at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkItemExecution.waitForCompletion(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:339)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.lambda$waitForItemsAndGatherFailures$2(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:131)
at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:31)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withoutLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:341)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withoutLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:326)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForItemsAndGatherFailures(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:127)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForItemsAndGatherFailures(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:89)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForAll(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:79)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForCompletion(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:67)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor.await(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:247)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexArchiveBuilderTaskDelegate.doProcess(DexArchiveBuilderTaskDelegate.kt:227)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexArchiveBuilderTask.doTaskAction(DexArchiveBuilderTask.kt:254)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.NewIncrementalTask$taskAction$$inlined$recordTaskAction$1.invoke(BaseTask.kt:69)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Blocks.recordSpan(Blocks.java:51)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.NewIncrementalTask.taskAction(NewIncrementalTask.kt:47)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:104)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalInputsTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalInputsTaskAction.java:32)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:51)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AbstractIncrementalTaskAction.execute(AbstractIncrementalTaskAction.java:25)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:29)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$3.run(TaskExecution.java:242)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeAction(TaskExecution.java:227)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeActions(TaskExecution.java:210)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeWithPreviousOutputFiles(TaskExecution.java:193)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.execute(TaskExecution.java:171)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.executeInternal(ExecuteStep.java:89)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.access$000(ExecuteStep.java:40)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:53)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:50)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:50)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:40)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:68)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:38)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:48)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:36)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:41)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:74)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:55)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:51)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:29)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:61)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:42)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:60)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:27)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.executeWithoutCache(BuildCacheStep.java:180)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.lambda$execute$1(BuildCacheStep.java:75)
at org.gradle.internal.Either$Right.fold(Either.java:175)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.caching.CachingState.fold(CachingState.java:59)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:73)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:48)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:36)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:25)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:36)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:22)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:110)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$2(SkipUpToDateStep.java:56)
at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:369)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:56)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:38)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:73)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:44)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:37)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:27)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:89)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:50)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:114)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:57)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:76)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:50)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.executeWithNoEmptySources(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:249)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:86)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:54)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.execute(RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.java:32)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.execute(RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.java:21)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:38)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:43)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:31)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.lambda$execute$0(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:40)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$4.withWorkspace(TaskExecution.java:287)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:40)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:30)
Caused by: org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Failed to process: D:\test\eighternityapp\build\app\tmp\kotlin-classes\debug, D:\test\eighternityapp\build\app\intermediates\javac\debug\classes
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.dexing.DexWorkAction.run(DexWorkAction.kt:53)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.profile.ProfileAwareWorkAction.execute(ProfileAwareWorkAction.kt:74)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:63)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:66)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:62)
at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:97)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.lambda$execute$0(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:62)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:44)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:41)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker.executeWrappedInBuildOperation(AbstractWorker.java:41)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:59)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor.lambda$submitWork$2(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:205)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runExecution(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:187)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.access$700(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:120)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner$1.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:162)
at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:31)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:270)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:119)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:124)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runBatch(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:157)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:126)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
... 5 more
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process: D:\test\eighternityapp\build\app\tmp\kotlin-classes\debug, D:\test\eighternityapp\build\app\intermediates\javac\debug\classes
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.dexing.DexWorkActionKt.process(DexWorkAction.kt:179)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.dexing.DexWorkActionKt.processNonIncrementally(DexWorkAction.kt:145)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.dexing.DexWorkActionKt.launchProcessing(DexWorkAction.kt:73)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.dexing.DexWorkAction.run(DexWorkAction.kt:45)
... 36 more
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Error while dexing.
at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveBuilder.getExceptionToRethrow(D8DexArchiveBuilder.java:140)
at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveBuilder.convert(D8DexArchiveBuilder.java:117)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.dexing.DexWorkActionKt.process(DexWorkAction.kt:175)
... 39 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete, origin: D:\test\eighternityapp\build\app\tmp\kotlin-classes\debug\com\example\eighternityApp\MainActivity.class
at Version.fakeStackEntry(Version_3.1.66.java:0)
at com.android.tools.r8.internal.pO0.a(SourceFile:68)
at com.android.tools.r8.internal.pO0.a(SourceFile:28)
at com.android.tools.r8.internal.pO0.a(SourceFile:27)
at com.android.tools.r8.internal.pO0.b(SourceFile:3)
at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(D8.java:11)
at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveBuilder.convert(D8DexArchiveBuilder.java:115)
... 40 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.internal.b: Type com.example.eighternityApp.MainActivity is defined multiple times: D:\test\eighternityapp\build\app\tmp\kotlin-classes\debug\com\example\eighternityApp\MainActivity.class, D:\test\eighternityapp\build\app\intermediates\javac\debug\classes\com\example\eighternityApp\MainActivity.class
at com.android.tools.r8.internal.jl1.a(SourceFile:14)
at com.android.tools.r8.internal.jl1.a(SourceFile:22)
at com.android.tools.r8.internal.mf1.b(SourceFile:6)
at com.android.tools.r8.internal.mf1.a(SourceFile:23)
at com.android.tools.r8.internal.mf1.a(SourceFile:10)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.merge(ConcurrentHashMap.java:2048)
at com.android.tools.r8.internal.mf1.a(SourceFile:6)
at com.android.tools.r8.graph.r2$a.f(SourceFile:4)
at com.android.tools.r8.dex.b.a(SourceFile:96)
at com.android.tools.r8.dex.b.a(SourceFile:21)
at com.android.tools.r8.D8.a(D8.java:21)
at com.android.tools.r8.D8.d(D8.java:11)
at com.android.tools.r8.D8.b(D8.java:1)
at com.android.tools.r8.internal.pO0.a(SourceFile:24)
... 43 more

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:dexBuilderDebug'.
> There was a failure while executing work items
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.dexing.DexWorkAction
    > Failed to process: D:\test\eighternityapp\build\app\tmp\kotlin-classes\debug, D:\test\eighternityapp\build\app\intermediates\javac\debug\classes

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 25s
```

Comment: "com.example.eighternityApp.MainActivity is defined multiple times"

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked. You are Gawd 

Comment: This solved for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66164771/type-project-com-project-mainactivity-is-defined-multiple-times

Answer (score 1):

Type project.com.project.MainActivity is defined multiple times

> ./project/build/app/intermediates/javac/debug/classes/project/com/project/MainActivity.class,
> ./project/build/app/tmp/kotlin-classes/debug/project/com/project/MainActivity.class

Answer (score 0):

check if there is any flavor management by chance and specify the main file to execute.